# Appending string data to top of text file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a little code at the bottom of my program that is supposed to add a text header to the beginning of my text file. The data writes to the bottom of the file. I was reading in 'Learn Python The Hard Way' that .seek(0) would put the insertion point at the beginning, which is at the location of 0 bytes. However, I must be implementing the function incorrectly.

```
print 'Now, I will write a header to the original file to display copyright.'

append_copy = open(filename, "a+")
append_copy.seek(0)
append_copy.write("Copyright -- Ryan -- 2014\n")
append_copy.close()

print 'File closed and data written!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer was absolutely correct that this cannot be done directly, but you do not need to create a temporary file to do what you want.

You *can* clobber files with Python, if you open them with the flag `w`, so you do not need to create a temporary file, assuming your original file was small enough to hold in memory.

```
filename = "Foo.txt";
print 'Now, I will write a header to the original file to display copyright.'

append_copy = open(filename, "r")
original_text = append_copy.read()
append_copy.close()

append_copy = open(filename, "w")
append_copy.write("Copyright -- Ryan -- 2014\n")
append_copy.write(original_text)
append_copy.close()

print 'File closed and data written!'
```

The clobbering is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

> 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be
>   erased)

Comment: This way actually totally makes sense. When opening up in "w" mode, the previous data is overwritten, correct?

Comment: @Simplex, Yes, it will destroy the previous file. More generally, this is basically what every text editor has to do: Load the file into memory, let you edit it, and then when you hit `save`, overwrite the original file.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing won't work, but what you want can't be done.

Opening a file in append mode means that **writes are always appended at the end of the file**. That's what "append" means, so that should not entirely be a surprise.

But **no filesystem allows inserting bytes at an arbitrary point** regardless. You will need to create a new file, write the desired bytes to it, copy the contents of the old file, delete or rename the old file, and then rename the new file.

Comment: So the most efficient way would to store the string data of existing file into a variable, writing the copyright text to the file, then appending the string data from previous file into the new copy file?

Comment: No. The most efficient way would be using something like [`copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) after writing the bytes to the new file.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: So just to make sure I understand correctly, so that I don't post a new question. The ONLY WAY to append a header line at the beginning of an already populated-by-text .txt file is by means of going through the already-populated-by-text file and saving its content, to then write that content in a new .txt file, file which has been previously populated with the header you want (a simple operation, just write a header to an empty .txt)? I have to do ''addition of a simple header'' in a .txt file with 100,000 lines and 6 columns. I cannot do it before it's populated.thanks